# ChromeDriver for NW.js Application

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am using chrome driver to drive my `NW.js` application. I am trying to automate my application which is a standalone. The Application build using NW.js technologies and based on chromium embedded framework.

NW.js is a desktop application with web technologies implementation. The Application to be tested is actually embedded inside the Web Took Kit and looks like a normal window application.

It does not make use any of the traditional browsers(IE/Firefox/Chrome/Safari etc.) I automated the basic login functionality of my application using selenium web driver with java program and when i run it, it invokes my application but unable to identify the objects in the App.

I am using the chrome driver, which makes use of chrome options, I have see in     the selenium documentation, that selenium now supports web view tags under this      link:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

It is given that Access to `<webview>` tags is now possible through `ChromeOptions.windowTypes`, but I don't see the `windowTypes` method for chrome options class, is the `<webview>` tag only supported for Mobile applications and not for NW.js desktop based applications with Web technologies implementation?

**After running my java program , I see the below errors displayed:**

---

```
 log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [file].
 log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
 Starting ChromeDriver (v2.2) on port 48743
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome    not reachable
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING:     The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.97 seconds
Build info: version: '2.49.0', revision:     '365eeb44deba2067b1761c8862ef21d55250e063', time: '2016-01-13 11:57:39'
System info: host: 'NT421', ip: '192.168.22.194', os.name: 'Windows 7',     os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>    (RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
    at functional.webStoreDummyTest.OpenSACITest.main(OpenSACITest.java:49)
```

---

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the issue

Comment: It is not clear if you are using the standard ChromeDriver or the customized ChromeDriver provided by NW.js. Try using the NW.js ChromeDriver as described in [NW.js documentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Test%20with%20ChromeDriver/)